# How to pass credentials with SDK_TEST_BASE_URL for android-sdk update?

Tags: android, authentication, android-sdk-tools

My machine locate in private network. Only way to connect maven repo - nexus proxy repository. I have proxy repository to `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/` and pass it to `SDK_TEST_BASE_URL`

```
export SDK_TEST_BASE_URL=https://nexus.corp/repository/raw-proxy/
```

I get `401` - that's good because env work:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://nexus.corp/repository/raw-proxy/repository2-1.xml
```

But when I pass `SDK_TEST_BASE_URL` with credentials I still see `401`:

```
export SDK_TEST_BASE_URL=https://ci_dos:PASS@nexus.corp/repository/raw-proxy/
sdkmanager --verbose --list
...
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://ci_dos:PASS@nexus.corp/repository/raw-proxy/repository2-1.xml
```

I tried to find some variables to pass credentials, but don't see any solutions.

How can I update sdk tools using Nexus proxy repository? Is it possible?